# MarkLogic xdmp.http* support for multiple Set-Cookie in Response Header

Tags: cookies, marklogic

It appears that the `xdmp.http*` functions (`xdmp.httpGet`, `xdmp.httpPost` etc.) in MarkLogic Servie-side JavaScript doesn't support multiple `Set-Cookie` in response header -- only one of the cookies is returned

> xdmp.httpGet('https://httpbin.org/response-headers?Set-Cookie=a&Set-Cookie=b')

```
{
  "code": 200, 
  "message": "OK", 
  "headers": {
    "access-control-allow-credentials": "true", 
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*", 
    "content-type": "application/json", 
    "date": "Thu, 11 Apr 2019 19:12:55 GMT", 
    "server": "nginx", 
    "set-cookie": "b", // only one cookie
    "content-length": "111", 
    "connection": "keep-alive"
  }
}
```

In comparison, the equivalent xdmp:http-* functions behave correctly:

> xdmp:http-get('https://httpbin.org/response-headers?Set-Cookie=a&Set-Cookie=b')

```xml
<response xmlns="xdmp:http">
  <code>200</code>
  <message>OK</message>
  <headers>
    <access-control-allow-credentials>true</access-control-allow-credentials>
    <access-control-allow-origin>*</access-control-allow-origin>
    <content-type>application/json</content-type>
    <date>Thu, 11 Apr 2019 19:21:40 GMT</date>
    <server>nginx</server>
    <set-cookie>a</set-cookie>  // both cookies
    <set-cookie>b</set-cookie>
    <content-length>111</content-length>
    <connection>keep-alive</connection>
  </headers>
</response>
```

Comment: Multiple set-cookie headers would be invalid use of http headers. I am confused though, as you show the use of request parameters, not request headers in your example.

Comment: Hi @grtjin. Multiple set-cookie in response headers is valid and xdmp:http-get parses it correctly (xdmp.httpGet doesn't). The URL I provided is for test purpose - it will produce two set-cookie entries in the response header.

Comment: Ok, things are clearer to me now. I'll file a bug and see what comes back..

Answer (score 1):

JSON can only represent one field per name.
The parser is obviously working.

Support for multi-value http headers in JSON appears missing.
There are many ways in which it could be done, but all would be internal fixes.

You could try calling `xdmp.eval` and using the XQuery version with XML results, and then reading the XML or transforming to JSON in a more suitable format.

Comment: Yes. This is the approach I am taking now while waiting for a fix by MarkLogic. Thanks!